# Register Button is not Working

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an android application, I want to send the user information to the database by clicking on Register Button and I want it to go to login page.I have created Intent to pass this activity to login activity. When I click register button the user input gets sent to the database but doesn't take you to Login activity. I check on the Logcat and it's not throwing any error. Anyone help me to figure this out, please?

here is my code:

```
registerbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("HELLO", "Register Button Clicked");
            //register();

            final String first_name = etfirstname.getText().toString();
            final String last_name = etlastname.getText().toString();
            final String email = etemail.getText().toString();
            final String password = etpass.getText().toString();
            //String Password2 = etpass2.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("HELLO Hello", "Register Button Clicked");
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if(success){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(AppRegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            //startActivity(intent);
                            AppRegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AppRegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create().show();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };
            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(first_name, last_name, email, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AppRegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);




        }



    });
```

Comment: add debugger point on `if(success)` and check the value , is it true? and why you have used `AppRegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);` instead of **startActivity(intent)**?

Comment: Have you checked if you are catching an Exception? That will probably tell you what your problem is.

Comment: @Sara Tirmizi I tried with startactivity(intent) but it didn't  make different. I will add the debugger after if(success). Will let you know.

Comment: @codeMagic I don't see any error to catch another exception. Usually, it gives you some error, doesn't it?

Comment: please cross  check that  what response u get.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code going into catch exception. Check it first

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, I figured out my problem. The problem was in the PHP script. I had declared five variables and use only four to post the user credential.